# npm install elasticsearch? version

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, npm

If I have node 6.11 version and npm 3.10.10 version installed (need these versions for company app purposes), which elasticsearch.js/ version do I need to install so I can connect angular with elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

To install the module into an existing Node.js project use npm:

```
npm install elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 0):

`elasticsearch.js` has no direct dependency on Node or NPM. Just use `npm install elasticsearch` and it will grab the latest version of the library.